# Can't install go modules

Tags: go

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on how to create a Go microservice but I keep getting this errors whenever I run go mod tidy.

```
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/velotiotech/watermark-service/internal
go: finding module for package github.com/lithammer/shortuuid/v3
go: finding module for package github.com/go-kit/kit/log
go: downloading github.com/go-kit/kit v0.12.0
go: downloading github.com/lithammer/shortuuid/v3 v3.0.7
go: downloading github.com/velotiotech/watermark-service v0.0.0-20200604060255-debbccd8157b
github.com/chococascante/focus-archery-api/pkg imports
        github.com/go-kit/kit/log: github.com/go-kit/kit@v0.12.0: verifying module: github.com/go-kit/kit@v0.12.0: initializing sumdb.Client: reading tree note: malformed note
note:

github.com/chococascante/focus-archery-api/pkg imports
        github.com/lithammer/shortuuid/v3: github.com/lithammer/shortuuid/v3@v3.0.7: verifying module: github.com/lithammer/shortuuid/v3@v3.0.7: initializing sumdb.Client: reading tree note: malformed note
note:

github.com/chococascante/focus-archery-api/pkg imports
        github.com/velotiotech/watermark-service/internal: github.com/velotiotech/watermark-service@v0.0.0-20200604060255-debbccd8157b: verifying module: github.com/velotiotech/watermark-service@v0.0.0-20200604060255-debbccd8157b: initializing sumdb.Client: reading tree note: malformed note
note:
```

Comment: The top google result for that error seems relevant: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38348

Answer (score 0):

Try disable the integrity check. Or try to change sum.golang.org to proxy.golang.org.

> go env -w GOSUMDB=off

Comment: If the problem is a corrupted local cache, you should fix the cache rather than ignore the integrity problems.